# change value in input field using radio button Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to find a way to enable the input field with a value and change it or deactivate it with value 0

```js
$("#tax").value(19).prop("disabled",false);

$("#tax").value(0).prop("disabled",true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>tax %</label><br>
<input type="radio" checked>Get tax
<input type="radio"> No tax

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="tax" id="tax" required="">
```

Comment: Firstly, it's not clear what you're trying to do. Secondly, the jQuery method to set the value of an input is `val()`

Answer (score 0):

Update input box value on changing radio button

```js
$('input[name=taxs]').change(function (e) {
  $('#tax_value').val(e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" name="taxs" value="10"> 10</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="taxs" value="20"> 20</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="taxs" value="30"> 30</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="taxs" value=""> No Tax</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="tax_value">
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `$("#tax").value(...`

with `$("#tax").val(...`